# JQuery tmpl knockout.js click not passing item

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, jquery-templates

I have a simple template block:

```
<script id="selectedCust" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
{{each people}}
<div class="section" personid="${Personid}" >
    <div class="sectionActions">
        <div>
           <a class="action" href="#" data-bind='click: removePerson'>Remove</a>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
{{/each}}
</script>
```

Simple HTML block:

```
<div id="customersArea" data-bind="template: 'selectedCust'">
</div>
```

with knockout js:

```
 function viewModel() {
            var self = this;
            self.people = ko.observableArray();
            self.removePerson = function (person, ev) {
                self.people.remove(person);
            };
            self.setPeople = function (ppl) {
                var len = ppl.length;
                for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    this.people.push(ppl[i]);
                }
            };
        }

    var mainViewModel = new viewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(mainViewModel, $("#customersArea")[0]);
```

I can set the people and see the databinding however when removePerson is called the person parameter is always the mainViewModel never the instance. When I try $root.remove I get the same results, trying $parent.remove I get $parent is undefined.

Without resorting to the ev parameter what am I doing wrong?

Adding Includes (in order), the #selectedCust block can be after this or right after knockout.js and it still errors out on $parent:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.0.6-development-only.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jQuery.tmpl.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/knockout-2.0.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.16.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-blockUI.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I just changed it to ko.js's templating:

```
<div class="section" data-bind="attr: { 'personid': PersonId }" >
    <div class="sectionActions">
        <div><a class="action" href="#" data-bind='click: $parent.removePerson'>Remove</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and that works... So is this an issue with knockout using tmpl?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
<div><a class="action" href="#" data-bind='click: $parent.removePerson'>Remove</a></div>
```

Per the knockout documentation "Note 1", you need to preface it with $parent when in a loop.  [Link](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html)

**EDIT**
BTW I figured I would share this here:

"Please note that, as of December 2011, jQuery.tmpl is no longer under active development. In due course, it will be succeded by JsRender, which is currently not yet in beta."
[LINK](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html)

Comment: I have tried that, and get a "Uncaught ReferenceError: $parent is not defined"

Comment: can you post your javascript includes?

Comment: After looking at this in more detail, is there a reason you have to use the jquery.tmpl?  Basically you cant access the ${personid} for sending it back to the viewModel.  Basically it works fine for display but if you want to do anything else with it, it wont work.  I was trying to work with it in this fashion click: function() { mainViewModel.removePerson(this) } but that sends the whole viewModel object.  jquery.tmpl I would say does not work in this situation.

Comment: I added a link that says that as of Dec 2011 jquery.tmpl is no longer being developed.

Comment: I wanted to work with a system that if I didn't want to keep knockout i could hard-code jquery to template.  It sucks cause if you go to the JsRender page it hasnt been touched in 4 months.

Comment: I used this example to do essentially the same thing.  W/O using jquery.tmpl.  I think if you ever decided to swap out knockout you wouldn't have to change that much.  http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/07/12/editing-a-variable-length-list-knockout-style/

Answer (score 0):

One issue I see right off is the div with class "section" is missing a closing "div" tag. I suspect this is creating malformed objects in the DOM.